# Select latest post for each blogger in the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, let's say I have 3 bloggers. Each of them have lots of posts.

I want to select latest post for each of them.

Currently I have this pseudo code:

```
Bloggers.find({name: {$in: ['John','Mike','Arny']}}, (err, bloggers) => {
    bloggers.forEach( blogger => {
        blogger.latest_post = Posts.find({author: blogger.name}).sort({date: -1}).limit(1);
    })
    displayItSomehow(bloggers);
})
```

Here, name of a blogger is name of a group. Each group has lots of docs, but I need only one accordingly to some criteria.

Blogger collection like this:

```
{name: 'John', id: 1},
{name: 'Mike', id: 2},
{name: 'Arny', id: 3}
```

Posts collection:

```
{ title: 'title1', text: 'blablabla', date: 111, author: 1 },
{ title: 'Nowadays football became...', text: 'blablabla', date: 112, author: 1 },
{ title: 'title1', text: 'blablabla', date: 113, author: 2 },
{ title: 'The story of my neighbor starts when...', text: 'blablabla', date: 114, author: 2 },
{ title: 'title1', text: 'blablabla', date: 115, author: 3 },
{ title: 'title1', text: 'blablabla', date: 116, author: 3 },
{ title: 'Business and success are always were...', text: 'blablabla', date: 117, author: 3 }
```

Result should be like this:

```
John:     'Nowadays football became...'

Mike:     'The story of my neighbor starts when...'

Arny:     'Business and success are always were...'
```

So, how can I solve my issue actually in mongoose? Is it possible with one query?

Comment: Please add the sample collection to the post both the bloggers and posts

Answer (score 0):

Query [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) is what you are looking for:

```
Bloggers
    .find({name: {$in: ['John','Mike','Arny']}})
    .populate({
        path: 'posts',
        options: {
            limit: 1,
            sort: {date: -1}
        }
    })
    .exec((err, bloggers) => {
        displayItSomehow(bloggers);
    })
})
```

Here's a link to the docs for the config object to the populate function: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate

This will only work, if you define your `Bloggers` schema accordingly:

```
var bloggerSchema = Schema({
    _id     : Number,
    name    : String,
    // all your other fields...
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});
```